# Checking if a user exists, and stopping a database insert (access database)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just don't know how to check if the users exists in the database and stop it from inserting a new row to the db (which will cause an error as I set the user to be a primary key)

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {

        OleDbConnection myconnection = new OleDbConnection();
        myconnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|Event.mdb";
        myconnection.Open();

        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand();
        myCommand.Connection = myconnection;
        myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        string query = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE uname = '{0}'");
        myCommand.CommandText = query;
        try
        {

            int amountOfUsers = (int)myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
            if (amountOfUsers < 1)
            {
                String myQuery = "insert into users (uname,upassword,email,type) Values   ('" + UserName.Text + "','" + Password.Text + "' ,'" + Email.Text + "',' user');";
                myCommand.CommandText = myQuery;
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Label1.Text = "user registered";
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "user already exists";
                UserName.Text = "";

                Email.Text = "";
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            myconnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. What is your question exactly? Do you get any exception or error message?

Comment: yes i get an exception  for having a duplicate value inside a primary key

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear at all but I can suggest a few things..

First of all, I think you forget to use your `uname` as a second parameter in your:

```
string query = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE uname = '{0}'");
```

line. You used `{0}` but never point any value to this parameter. (I assume you don't have a username called `{0}`) Like;

```
string query = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE uname = '{0}'", UserName.Text);
```

As a second, please always use [*parameterized queries*](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of string concatenations are open for *[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)* attakcs.

Like;

```
String myQuery = "insert into users (uname,upassword,email,type) Values (@uname, @upassword, @email, @type)";
OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", UserName.Text);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@upassword", Password.Text);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", Email.Text);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", "user");
```

> i want to check if the username in UserName.Text is availble in the
>   data base or no and if it does i want to stop from inserting new data

Than you should use `SELECT` first to check your username is exist in your database or not like;

```
string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname = '{0}'", UserName.Text);
OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand();
myCommand.CommandText = query;
SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
if(reader.HasRows)
{
  //Your username exist in your database
}
else
{
  //Doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: i want to check if the username in UserName.Text is availble in the data base or no and if it does i want to stop from inserting new data

Comment: @user3132548 Updated in my answer. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

correct your query:

```
query = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE uname = '{0}'" ,UserName.Text );
```

Comment: @user3132548 - if this solution works for you, then you can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have missing the parameter uname , you have pass the text of UserName textbox to uname

for eg

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE uname='" + UserName.Text +"'
```